# Convert OLS results into an array or DataFrame

Tags: arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe, statsmodels

I want to access `b` like an `numpy` `array` or `pandas` `DataFrame`

```
m = smapi.OLS(Y, X).fit()
b = m.params
```

I want to access `b` like `b[-1, :]` and / or `b.iloc[-1, :]`

Comment: What is `b` as of now? Is it not an array?

Comment: I do not know. When I try something like above I get `unhashable type`

Comment: b is already a pandas Series if Y and X are pandas Series too. You can call `to_frame` method on it but I don't see why it would be necessary. Since it is a Series there is only one index: `b.iloc[0]`, `b.iloc[-1]` etc. If you called OLS on numpy arrays, the result is also an array so you need to access with `b[0]` or `b[-1]`